# Touch ID IOS 10 takes 10 - 15 sec to respond

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, touch

I`m trying to implement touch ID into my app.
I get the touch ID to work, but it takes 10 - 15 sec before I get pushed to the next Viewcontroller.
I have searched about the topic, and it seems the solution is to run this in the main thread.
I then changed my code to run this as the main thread ( I think ), but the problem is still there.
Can anybody see whats wrong?

```
func logMeIn(){

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "notesVC", sender: self)
}


@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let context:LAContext = LAContext()

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil){
        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Log in", reply: { (wasSuccessful, error) in
            if wasSuccessful{
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({() -> Void in })
                self.logMeIn()
            }
            else {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        })
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That is not how you run something on the main thread. You have to do `DispatchQueue.main.async{//write the code you want to run on the main thread here}`. Or if you want to stick with `OperationQueue`, you still need to move all code that needs to run on the main thread **inside** the closure of `addOperation`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works fine when I did this:  if wasSuccessful{
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({() -> Void in self.logMeIn()})

Comment: Glad it worked. I have posted my comment as an answer, so others experiencing the same issue can find it easier. If you found it useful, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you run something on the main thread. You need to move all code that needs to run on the main thread inside the closure of addOperation, like this:

```
if wasSuccessful{
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({() -> Void in self.logMeIn()})
}
```

Or you can also do

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    //write the code you want to run on the main thread here
}
```